# How to change background color of bottomnavigationItem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I tried following code but it does not working

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/tinpay3.svg"),
            label: "TINPAY",
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 194, 44, 1.0),
           )
```

I want to change background color like that. [image]. SO How to change background color of bottomnavigationItem?

Answer (score 0):

`BottomNavigationBar` has these color arguments:

```
fixedColor: ...,
backgroundColor: ...,
selectedItemColor: ...,
unselectedItemColor: ...,
```

and `BottomNavigationBarItem` has:

```
backgroundColor: ...,
```

Maybe you should use them?

**UPDATED**

I think you can use `activeIcon` parameter and set it to another image:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/tinpay3.svg"),
  activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/tinpay3_reversed.svg"),
  label: "TINPAY",
  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 194, 44, 1.0),
),
```

where `tinpay3_reversed.svg` is the reverse of `tinpay3.svg` with white letters and colored background.

Comment: in my exaple as you can see i used background color but it did not work

Comment: You have 3 different styles, whereas `BottomNavigationBar` supports only two: "selected" and "unselected". What is the difference between No 3 and No 4?

Comment: I tried all styles but it only changes text color.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `activeIcon` to another image?

Comment: yes I have and it looked very bad and  the image was on center , the rest was white . it did not cover full bottomnavigationITem

Comment: The icon and the image are separate items. I am not sure whether you can turn off the display of the labels and just put the labels as part of the image. Just leave the label argument off.

Comment: I did not use label when setting another image

Comment: Please update your question and put your latest code and show the whole `BottomNavigationBar` creation code.